# Python - For Loop That Prints Each Number And Its Square on a Separate Line

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, integer

I have a list of numbers:

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
```

My first task was to print each number on a new line, like this:

```
12
10
32
3
66
17
42
99
20
```

I was able to do this by creating a for loop that printed the integers in the list:

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
for i in nums:
    print(i)
```

Now I need to write another for loop that prints each number and its square on a new line, like this:

```
The square of 12 is 144
The square of 10 is 100 
The square of 32 is 1024
The square of 3 is 9
The square of 66 is 4356
The square of 17 is 289
The square of 42 is 1764
The square of 99 is 9801
The square of 20 is 40
```

So far I have actually been able to print the squared values, but can't get them on separate lines by themselves. I also need to rid of the brackets around the values.

**My attempt:**

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
for i in nums:
    print(i)

squared = [ ]

for i in nums:
    squared.append(i * i)
    print("The square of", i, "is", squared)
```

**Resulted in:**

```
12
10
32
3
66
17
42
99
20
The square of 12 is [144]
The square of 10 is [144, 100]
The square of 32 is [144, 100, 1024]
The square of 3 is [144, 100, 1024, 9]
The square of 66 is [144, 100, 1024, 9, 4356]
The square of 17 is [144, 100, 1024, 9, 4356, 289]
The square of 42 is [144, 100, 1024, 9, 4356, 289, 1764]
The square of 99 is [144, 100, 1024, 9, 4356, 289, 1764, 9801]
The square of 20 is [144, 100, 1024, 9, 4356, 289, 1764, 9801, 400]
```

I need to get rid of the brackets and need to only include one squared value per line (that corresponds with the integer to the left). How should I do this?

Comment: Why build a list? Why not use `print()` in the *first* loop you created to also print the `i * i` result?

Comment: Follow the same approach from your first example and just print inside your loop: `print("The square of", i, "is", i * i)`. You don't need to collect the values in a new list.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that - yes it works as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you actually want to track the squares or if that was just part of your effort to get them printed.

Assuming you did want to track the squares, a minor change would be:

https://repl.it/GLmw

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
for i in nums:
    print(i)

squared = [ ]

for i in nums:
    sqr = i * i
    squared.append(sqr)
    print("The square of {} is {}".format(i, sqr))
```

This allows you to have the current square ready to work with without having to reference it from the array.

If you really did mean to reference the squared value from the array, you'd use a negative index to fetch from the end of the array:

https://repl.it/GLms

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
for i in nums:
    print(i)

squared = [ ]

for i in nums:
    squared.append(i*i)
    print("The square of {} is {}".format(i, squared[-1]))
```

Comment: Using the negative index gives me 400 for every squared result, but your first block of code does what I was looking for. Except, Is there any way to print a result without the commas? I'm currently getting ('The square of', 12, 'is', 144)

And if I try to do: print("The square of" + i + "is" + sqr) I get the error message: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Any idea how to fix this? 

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: @HappyHands31 I apologize for that. I was still partially in a Python 2 state of mind. I've updated the code to Python 3, fixed a bug in the second chunk, and added some online demos.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly now. Would you mind explaining this a little bit? When you say print("The square of {} is {}".format(i, sqr)), it looks like you're doing string substitution? And the values that you're substituting the {}'s for are "i" and "sqr"....so the line "squared.append(sqr)" is what's making sure that we're on the current square in the array? That way whenever you reference "sqr" in the print statement it knows to print out the next square value each time? Is that correct?

Comment: @HappyHands31 `squared` isn't used for anything but storage for future unwritten code. `sqr` keeps track of the current squared value which is then used to both append to the array and to assemble into a string. `sqr` gets re-initialized each time through the loop using the current value of `i`. [`.format()` is described here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#format).

Answer (score 2):

```
nums = (12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20)

for i in nums:
    print(i)

for i in nums:
    print("the square of",i,"is", i**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
for i in nums:
    print(i**2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should describe any code you post so that the asker and the community can understand it better, no matter how small it is.